# Create and instance of a Dictionary(Of K,V) with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: vb.net, types, generics, activator

Given the below code, I'm trying to create a new instance of a `Dictionary(Of String, ??)` based on a `ItemType` variable I have. How do I construct the `DictType` so that I can use `Activator` to create an Instance of the type I'm after?

```
                Dim ItemType As Type            ' Data type of dictionary value
                Dim DictType As Type = ????     ' Dictionary(of String, ItemType)
                Dim NewDict = Activator.CreateInstance(DictType)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a method parameter or local variable of type `Type` whose name is `typeVariable`.  Then the answer is:

```
Dim dictType = GetType(Dictionary(Of ,)).MakeGenericType(GetType(String), typeVariable)
```

See the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) for examples, including one using Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `GetType` method.  This will return a `Type` instance from a stated / bindable type name.  For example

```
Dim dictType = GetType(Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
Dim newDict = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType)
```

**EDIT**

Here's the version to create the `Dictionary(Of Key, Value)` type when not all of the types are known at compile time

```
Dim itemType As Type = ...
Dim dictRaw = GetType(Dictionary(Of ,))
Dim dictType = dictRaw.MakeGenericType(GetType(String), itemType)
Dim value = Activator.CreateInstance(dictType)
```

Comment: But the second type is not known at compile time, so this won't work.

Comment: @phoog, gotcha. Updated my answer to show that scenario as well